# How do I call a Vue.js function from an external JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have to call a Vue.js function from an external JavaScript file, but it's not working. Below I have given the code that I have tried.

```
// external js file 
import vm from './vue.js';

function callingVuejsFunction(data) {  
    this.vm.displayData()
}

// Vuejs file
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        firstname : '' ,
        lastname  :  ''
    },
    methods:{
        displayData: function( ) {
            alert()
        } 
    } 
})
```

Comment: try `vm.displayData()` instead `this.vm.displayData()`

Comment: its not calling.

Comment: You need the reference to your Vue application - not to the Vue framework itself. Change the `main.js` in your Vue application so that it assigned the root Vue instance to a global variable (e.g. `window.myApp`) and then refer to this variable in your external script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vm.$options.methods.displayData()`:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firstname: '',
    lastname: ''
  },
  methods: {
    displayData: function(msg) {
      alert(msg)
    }
  }
})

vm.$options.methods.displayData('I was called externally!')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Props for an example that runs in the stackoverflow window 

Answer (score 0):

```html
export default { 
    methods:{
      my_function(){
        alert('vue function trigger!!!')
      }
    },
    created () { 
        let _this = this 
        window.addEventListener('ready', function() { 
          _this.my_function()
        })
       
    }
}
```

Here is the perfect example of calling a vue method from javascript.